# CreateExcelDoc class has error

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I found this code that is a simple Class that allows you to create Excel documents fairly easily.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20228/Using-C-to-Create-an-Excel-Document

I had to change some the way some of the variables are called because of conflicting references.

`private Excel.Application app = null;` has now become 
`private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = null;`

That worked for every place except one. `worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];`

This line gives me the `Error   69 One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?`

I'm stumped.

Comment: Um...I really can't understand your broken English. Also, I can't figure out what you are trying to tell me to do

Comment: In the code you use (according to link in your question) there is a missing declaration at the top of the code: `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`. If I added it everything worked fine. Hope my English is much better this time :)

Comment: I did what you told me to which helped clean up the code. (Now I only have to put `Excel.Application` or `Excel.Workbook`) but the error in the original post is still happening at the `worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];` line. And I've copied the code directly from the OP's link.

Answer (score 0):

I added the `Micrsoft.CSharp` reference and the error went away